# Select by index and by boolean indexing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, object-slicing

Input program:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A" : ["A0","A1","A2","A3"],
                   "B" : ["dog","cat","dog","dog"]})

myindexes = pd.Index([1,2])

    A    B
0  A0  dog
1  A1  cat
2  A2  dog
3  A3  dog
```

I want to modify `df` to get the following output datframe:

```
       A    B
0     A0  dog
1     A1  cat
2  match  dog
3     A3  dog
```

I'm trying to do selection by index values (using the variable `myindexes`) **and** selection by boolean indexer (must be `dog` in the column `B`).

Pandas doesn't tolerate the following line...But that's the idea I'm trying to express:

```
df.loc[(myindexes) & (df["B"] == "dog"), "A"] = "match"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `(myindexes)`, use `df.index.isin(myindexes)`:

```
df.loc[df.index.isin(myindexes) & (df["B"] == "dog"), "A"] = "match"
```

Output:

```
>>> df
       A    B
0     A0  dog
1     A1  cat
2  match  dog
3     A3  dog
```